# Change color of "Post Your Answer" button

Tags: feature-request, design

Multiple times, happen to me that when making a stack snippet code and I want to test the code (i.e I want to press "Run Code Snippet" button), I press the incorrect button "Post Your Answer" because they have the same color and they are close to each other. After this, of course, I have to delete my incomplete answer. Check next image for understand:

[image]

Maybe, it will be better for the user to change the color of the button "Post Your Answer" to green (a color more coherent with the action) just to give some contrast with the others buttons. Another approach, could be adding a confirmation dialog before posting a new answer, but I will like more the first option.

Comment: I'd actually prefer the Run Code Snippet to get its color changed, preferably to a light blue or cyan. But I see why you'd want some change to this.

Comment: OP and @DavyM made a good point. It's something that's been bugging me without even realizing it. Would be nice if the `run code snippet` was a slightly different color.

Comment: I'd much rather have a conformation dialog.